# SAP - Autologoff ignores scripting action

Tags: sap-gui

I automated our SAP system using SAP Gui Scripting. After 30 minutes where the script works, our SAP system logs off (auto-logoff) because it doesn't recognize the activities of the script. Is there a parameter to change this?

Don't missunterstand me - I don't want to deactivate auto logoff. I want SAP to recognize the script activities so auto logoff woulnd't be performed as long as my script is working.

Regards and thank you,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

For me, for this reason, the following script runs automatically the whole day after logging in:

```
If Not IsObject(application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
   Set connection = application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session    = connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session,     "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject application, "on"
End If
wscript.sleep 2000

do
'if time() > "16:00" then exit do
on error resume next
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
if err.number <> 0 then exit do
on error goto 0

session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "/o"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[1]").close
wscript.sleep 29000
Loop
```

Regards,
ScriptMan